# To what extent is traditional theology relevant to simulated realities?

Tags: reference-request, theology, artificial-intelligence

I've noticed from playing with the old Sims game that I have some of the attributes of God - I'm completely independent of them, I have an isolated moral framework, I can surround them with grills and burn them alive (and they can't do that to me), etc.

Are any traditional theologies or religious philosophies directly applicable to the creator of a virtual reality and/or the player of a godlike role in a video game environment?

Comment: Scientific speculation. The stuff of AI is still only speculation. Why not then speculate on the impact of unicorns on the environment also?

Comment: I actually do think this question is interesting ... but it doesn't appear to fall within the scope of this SE.

Comment: @virmaior, is there a way to reword the question to make it fall within the scope of the philosophy stack exchange? I couldn't find a theology stack exchange and this one had similar questions asked in it.

Comment: I don't participate there so I don't know but ... you could go for christianity.SE or maybe islam.SE ? Other than that worldbuilding.SE ?

Comment: I edited to highlight the on-topic question I perceive here, feel free to revert if it does not match your intention.

Comment: @virmaior Voting to reopen --as it stands now, this is a straightforward reference request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually working on a book that touches on this very topic right now.  A couple of places to get started:

- If you read Bostrom's [Simulation Argument](http://www.simulation-argument.com) he actually explicitly draws a connection between his concept that we are likely living in a simulated reality and traditional theology.
- A number of traditional theologies, particularly those that trace back to Plato and the neo-Platonics deal directly with the concept of living in an [unreal world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave), and the moral implications and quest for meaning in that context.
- Descartes talks in the [Meditations](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/descartes/1639/meditations.htm) about the necessity to be able to trust the ultimate author of reality.

Comment: I'm looking forward to reading that book. Thomas Paine wrote in The Age of Reason that the "study of theology, as it stands in Christian churches, is the study of nothing." It may be that you're making that no longer true!